# Firebase Authentication Integrating multiple providers

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication, google-authentication

I've read the documentation about the integration of Facebook and Google sign in and I want to integrate both the methods in my app. I want user to sign up using either of the provider and once account created, can login through the same provider like usual other apps. I'm unable to find out the approach to do so and also I'm a newbie to the android development. I've implemented Google sign in already. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Recommending libraries or off-site tutorials is off topic on Stack Overflow. That said: have you seen FirebaseUI? It has a great auth module that seriously simplifies [integrating Firebase Authentication into Android apps](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth).

Comment: Yes, I'm looking into it!